# How to create a button in QT with multiple properties?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to create a button with the following properties

1. translucent
2. WordWrap
3. Relative font size
4. When you click on the button, the text color and the background color of the button changes

I can achieve those separately with

**translucent and a changing colors**

```
button->setFlat(true);
button->setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {"
            "color: blue;"
            "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 90)"
            "}"
            "QPushButton:pressed {"
            "color: lime;"
            "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50)"
            "}"
            "QPushButton:flat {"
            "border: none; "
            "}"
            );
```

**word wrapping:**

```
   QPushButton button;
    QHBoxLayout layout;
    button.setLayout(&layout);
    QLabel label("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONGGGGGGGGGGG TEXXXXXXXXXT");
    label.setWordWrap(true);
    layout.addWidget(&label);
    button.show();
```

**Relative font size:**

```
void MyButton::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    int pixelsHeight = this->size().height()/2;
    if(pixelsHeight > 24) pixelsHeight = 24;
    if(pixelsHeight < 8) pixelsHeight = 8;

    m_font.setPixelSize(pixelsHeight);
    label->setFont(m_font);
}
```

How can I achieve all at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I just put all what you wrote in subclass. Is what you need?

*.h

```
#ifndef MYBUTTON_H
#define MYBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QResizeEvent>


class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyButton(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

private:
    QLabel * label;
    QFont *m_font;

};

#endif // MYBUTTON_H
```

*.cpp

```
#include "mybutton.h"

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{
    setFlat(true);
    setStyleSheet(
                "QPushButton {"
                "color: blue;"
                "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 90)"
                "}"
                "QPushButton:pressed {"
                "color: lime;"
                "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50)"
                "}"
                "QPushButton:flat {"
                "border: none; "
                "}"
                );

     QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
     setLayout(layout);
     label = new QLabel("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONGGGGGGGGGGG TEXXXXXXXXXT",this);
     label->setWordWrap(true);
     layout->addWidget(label);

     m_font = new QFont();

}

void MyButton::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    int pixelsHeight = this->size().height()/2;
    if(pixelsHeight > 24) pixelsHeight = 24;
    if(pixelsHeight < 8) pixelsHeight = 8;

    m_font->setPixelSize(pixelsHeight);
    label->setFont(*m_font);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mybutton.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyButton but;
    but.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Привет с cyberforuma ахах У меня куча наработок уже есть, но решил задать пространный вопрос в ожидании готового решения.

Comment: Hello, but don't use native language on this forum, my subclass do, what you want or not?

Comment: What do you think?
He does, but very poorly.